# Is $(f_1(x)+f_2(y)+f_3(z))\vec{r}$ irrotational?

Tags: calculus, vector-fields, curl

If we define $F(x,y,z)\equiv f_1(x)+f_2(y)+f_3(z)$, the curl of $\vec{f}(\vec{r})=F(x,y,z)\vec{r}=(F\cdot x,F\cdot y,F\cdot z)$ would be

\begin{align*}
\nabla\times\vec{f}&=
\begin{vmatrix}
\hat{i} & \hat{j} & \hat{k} \\
\partial_x & \partial_y & \partial_z \\
Fx & Fy & Fz
\end{vmatrix}\\
&=(z\partial_y F-y\partial_z F,x\partial_z F-z\partial_x F,y\partial_x F-x\partial_y F)\\
&= (zf_2'-yf_3', xf_3'-zf_1',yf_1'-xf_2')\neq \vec 0
\end{align*}
The problem is that others got that it is $\vec 0$. I'm not sure whether who's wrong.

Comment: You expression is correct. It is not zero in general.

Comment: Special cases are a good way to get counterexamples. For instance, what if $f_2=f_3=0$?

Comment: Right, so it isn't a central field.